# jquery if statement and remove iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i write an if statement in jquery:

IF the user clicks on an image `div#ProductImages > img` then hide/remove the iframe?

This is what i have:
(my code will append the youtube video to a div location on the page)

I need to remove the iframe once the user starts clicking on the images again.

```
var $video=$('div.icon iframe');
var $productImage=$('.product-image');
var $icon=$('.icon');
$icon.on('click',function()
{
    $('.product-image').append($video);
});
```

**EDIT: sorry i meant remove**
http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMF/1/

Comment: Hide or remove? those are two very different things (one is CSS, and the other is removing the DOM element entirely from existence).

Comment: If you want to hide, set it's `.style.display="none"`

Comment: Actually "display='none'" is removing from the DOM-tree( but not the DOM). "visibillity='hide'" is hiding :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide:

```
$('#my-iframe').hide();
```

To remove:

```
$('#my-iframe').remove();
```

It is not clear from your example what logic you're trying to place where.

But you would need some kind of click listener.

```
$('#my-image').click(function() {
    // hide or remove iframe
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the $video and toggle visibillity

```
var $video=$('div.icon iframe');
var $productImage=$('.product-image');
var $icon=$('.icon');
$('.product-image').append($video);
$icon.on('click',function()
{
    $video.toggle();
});
```

​
I hope I understood you correctly